# how to define a static variable of generic type

Tags: c++

I have written a class as below:

```
template <class T>
/* Abstract class for stack n queue */
class StacknQueue
{
public:
    StacknQueue(int = 10);
    virtual int insert(const T&) = 0;
    virtual int remove(T&) = 0;
    virtual void display() = 0;
    int isEmpty() const {return top == -1 || front == -1 || front > top ;}
    int isFull() const { return top == size - 1 ;}
    //virtual int isQEmpty const() = 0;
    //virtual int isQFull const() = 0;

    void initialize();
    static int flag;
    static int size;
    //int rear;
    static int front;
    static int top;
    static T *stknqPtr ;
};
```

when I try to define the variable stknqPtr outside class as below:

```
template <class T>
    T StacknQueue<T> :: stknqPtr = new T[size];
```

its giving me error:

```
error C2040: 'stknqPtr' : 'float' differs in levels of indirection from 'float *'
```

I am new to c++ can anyone suggest me how to proceed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your definition has the wrong type. It fails to define a pointer. It should be:

```
template <class T>
T* StacknQueue<T>::stknqPtr = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it the right type - It's `T*` in the class, but `T` in the definition.

But - your class design suggests that all it's members should not be static - otherwise every instance is going to share the same backing-data - not what you usually want for a stack or queue. And for non-static members you dont need the annoying explicit instantiation - so everything becomes easy.

Comment: No you don't need explicit instantiations for each type, http://ideone.com/P4AyH2

Comment: @vsoftco - You're spot on - I must be misremembering something. Consider it erased.

Comment: @vsoftco Just to be clear though - you must put that in the definition in the _.h_, not in a seperate _.cpp_ file like you would for a normal, non-templated static member.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson yes, indeed, otherwise it won't be ODR-ed.